# Return a JSON Object after clicking on donut Chart (c3js)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, c3.js

I use [c3js](http://c3js.org/) in my web application, I have added a [Donut Chart](http://c3js.org/samples/chart_donut.html) into my View and it all works fine !

But, when I want to retrieve the JSON object from the clicked zone, I receive an object of the type SVGPathElement after displaying it in the console, I try to convert it to JSON but doesn't work:

How do I get the data from the clicked element?

My code is similar to that :

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30],
            ['data2', 120],
        ],
        type : 'donut',
        onclick: function (d, i) { console.log("onclick", d, i); },
        onmouseover: function (d, i) { console.log("onmouseover", d, i); },
        onmouseout: function (d, i) { console.log("onmouseout", d, i); }
    },
    donut: {
        title: "Iris Petal Width"
    }
});
```

Comment: The parameter `d` should contain all the data that you need, can you post your actual code and your expected output please.

Comment: Thank you very much George, after editing my script, ir return JSON object, it work fine ! but how can i use this object and send it to my action controller ? i try to add php code into JS but doesn't work ... please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can send it using ajax**

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30],
            ['data2', 120],
        ],
        type : 'donut',
        onclick: function (d, i) { 

$.ajax({
url:'your server php file',
headers:{/*some headers*/},
data:JSON.stringify(d),
}).then(function(data){
    //do something in success
 })

}

    },
    donut: {
        title: "Iris Petal Width"
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Rami for help .
Your code does'nt work, but is still correct .. just you must change data:JSON.stringify(d) to  data:{"output":JSON.stringify(d)}} .  
Output is a variable is used in Controller, it contains final object.. Thank you very much .. you are helpful !